# send email to a group of user using three state workflow

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server

I've created a request form using a custom list. And I also have added a three-state workflow to send an email after a new item has been created in the list. For now, I can only send the email to the requester and also another one user. My problem is, I need to send the email to a group of users who is the administrator of the page.

I can't use Sharepoint Designer or MS InfoPath due to permissions are not granted.

How can I do that? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can ask admin to create security group and send email through SharePoint send email utility.
However, If you again want to send email to a outlook DL without using GraphAPI or Outlook APIs then you can trigger a HTTP trigger flow from your sharepoint page and send all Email, Body, Subject as payload and then use O365 outlook action in flow.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could set alert in the list to remind the administrator of the page that there is a new item added in the list.

[image]

Comment: I got this error when I try to send an alert ; "You cannot create alerts for lists for which users can only read their own items." How can I solve this?

Comment: Go to List Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Set Read access as "Read all items".